# Yii2: How to use radio button value in controller for further execution?

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, radiobuttonlist

I need to choose a value from the radio list. If a particular value is selected then only next execution will happen other wise just update should happen.

Radio List-

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->radioList(array('Approved'=>'Approved','Digital'=>'Digital','CDP'=>'CDP','Print'=>'Print','Other Process'=>'Other Process','Packing'=>'Packing','Dispatch'=>'Dispatch'),['class' => $model->status ? 'btn-group' : 'btn btn-default'],['id'=>'radioButtons'] );
```

Controller-

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Status();


        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
        {
               if(radio button value is approved or dispatch below code should execute )
              {
                Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                ->setFrom('abc@gmail.com')
                ->setTo('qwer@hotmail.com')
                ->setSubject('Message subject')
                ->setTextBody('Plain text content')
                ->setHtmlBody('<b>HTML content</b>')
                ->send();
                }
                  else{ 
                         (just update the form )
                    }

                $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } 
        else 
        {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

I know its pretty easy but not finding a way to implement it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check `$model->status` attribute for this values.

```
if($model->status == 'Approved' || $model->status == 'Dispatch')
{
    //do stuff
}
```

To make it easy I suggest to you store your values as constants. E.g.

```
class MyActiveRecord extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    const STATUS_APPROVED = 1;
    const STATUS_DISPATCH = 2;
    //and so on

    public static function getStatusList()
    {
         return [
             self::STATUS_APPROVED => 'Approved',
             self::STATUS_DISPATCH => 'Dispatch',
             //other values
         ];
    }
}
```

And then in controller

```
if($model->status == MyActiveRecord::STATUS_APPROVED ||
   $model->status == MyActiveRecord::STATUS_DISPATCH)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Also it will make your view more readable:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->radioList($model->getStatusList())?>
```

Comment: <?= $form->field($model, 'status')->radioList($model->getStatusList())?>
if I wrote this in my form how to make radio list containing other options?

Comment: `getStatusList()` - here you return an array of all possible statuses, so radio list with all values will be generated

Comment: Class 'Yii\db\ActiveRecord' not found getting this error whats wrong

used-
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
at top

Comment: `getStatusList()` how to write it can you please explain

Comment: Its just a class method. I've provide example in the answer. Just add other statuses and define constants for them.

Comment: Calling unknown method: backend\models\Status::getStatusList() getting this error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83400/discussion-between-tony-and-saurabh).